# UINavigationController: pushViewController – title out of bounds

Tags: ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, title, pushviewcontroller

I've got a navigation controller inside an UIView. It's smaller and it's on the left side. When I push the view with that controller I can see the new title coming from the right which is fine, but during the animation the title is visible out of the bounds of that UINavigationView – crosses the right bound of that view (since it's coming from the right obviously)! You can see it better with longer titles. It looks unacceptable.

Is it because navigation views are supposed to be used only on full screen or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Where do you set your title ?
try to set your title in viewDidAppear instead of viewDidLoad or viewWillApper, i think you will get the expected result.

Comment: I put it into `viewDidLoad`. Thanks for your suggestions, but:
1. Putting it into `viewDidAppear` makes it only invisible until the view appears (still pushing the view back makes the title go out of bounds).  2. Putting into `viewWillAppear` changes nothing